# Friendly_id gem: updating fields doesn't use candidates array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I have my slug candidates set as :

```
def slug_candidates
  [
    :full_name,
    [:full_name, :location],
    :display_name
  ]
end

def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    full_name_changed? || location_changed? || display_name_changed?
end
```

But if I update the `display_name`, the slug generated is the display name -- even though the first candidate is available (full_name).

Any idea on why that would be the case?

Shouldn't updating a field look at the candidates array again to generate the new slug?

Comment: I think that the `should_generate_new_friendly_id?` method is going to take whatever is changed, and update the slug.  So that seems to be the case with you.

Comment: For anyone that finds this in the future, Hopstream has reached out to the FriendlyId creators in a Github Issue: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/508

Comment: @tdooner Yeah, seems to be a bug in Friendly_id. Found a temporary way around for this for now (posted on github).